# How can I tell how much space is taken up by photos vs. videos on Google Photos?

Tags: google-photos

Now that [Google Photos no longer offers free photo/video storage](https://www.theverge.com/2020/11/11/21560810/google-photos-unlimited-cap-free-uploads-15gb-ending#:%7E:text=Google%20One%20pricing%20is%20not,30TB%20(%24149.99%20%2F%20month).), I'm wondering if switching to another service is the better option. To further complicate matters, the old photos/videos before June 2021 are still being stored for free.

One thing that will help inform the decision is if I knew how much storage is taken up by videos vs. how much is taken by photos.

The only mentions of how much storage is taken up were:

- Google Photos > Storage: This shows the total storage taken up by Google Photos. It does not show me how much are videos vs. photos. It also does not show me how many are stored in the service for free (i.e. uploaded before June 2021).
- Google Photos > Storage > Review and delete > Large photos & videos: This only shows me a subset of videos and photos that are big. It does not provide aggregate information as to how much is videos and how much is storage (e.g. I would need to filter and sum them up). It's not clear if these are all the videos/photos uploaded after June 2021, or if there are some videos/photos that were uploaded prior to June 2021. It likely doesn't report small videos / photos uploaded after June 2021.

In other words, both of these don't show me the exact data I want:

- Photo storage prior to June 2021.
- Video storage prior to June 2021.
- Photo storage after June 2021.
- Video storage after June 2021.

Assuming there is no easy way to get at those 4 bits of data, I would be satisfied with knowing just total photo storage + total video storage. By storage I mean how much space it would take would I transfer it to another service (i.e. completely disregard that anything uploaded before June 2021 takes up 0 bytes).

Comment: You might be interested in this (unfortunately unanswered) question: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/168287/how-to-bulk-identify-google-photos-media-items-that-count-towards-storage-quota

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the only way I found to do this is to export all your data, which can both take a while and take up a lot of space on your harddrive:

1. Visit https://takeout.google.com/
2. Export your photos data
3. Download your photos data
4. Unzip your photos data
5. Separate by file type
6. Measure the amount of space taken